# transform doesn't work on position fixed divs on android

Tags: html, css

I make divs move using css transitions, which works great however not on android.

if the div is position:fixed, nothing happens

original div:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:4;
    float:left;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
```

class I add to move it:

```
.show-left-menu {
    transform: translate(79%,0);
    -ms-transform: translate(79%,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(79%,0);
}
```

It works if I change to position:relative but its a sticky header so needs to be fixed

Comment: I have exact same problem, using default browser @ android 2.2 (the first to support fixed)

Comment: I managed to fix this but its not great.if you make your div position:absolute, but put it inside a positon:fixed container, you can apply the transition to the absolute div and it works, but stays 'fixed' when scrolling because of its parent container... if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Android has a bug, even on 4.0 that isn't fixed until 4.1+.

**TL;DR:**

This won't work on Android:

```
<div class="side-menu"></div>

.side-menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: -70px;
}
.side-menu.show {
  transform: translateX(70px);
}
```

This **will work**, and is basic normal CSS so will not affect other browsers too:

```
<div class="side-menu-fixer">
  <div class="side-menu"></div>
</div>

.side-menu-fixer {
  position: fixed;
}
.side-menu {
  position: position;
  left: -70px;
}
.side-menu.show {
  transform: translateX(70px);
}
```

**Explanation:**
On Android 4.0, we can't use `transform`s CSS on `position:fixed` elements, it's a bug. To get around this, `rpsep2` idea of wrapping your fixed position element in another div which has `position:fixed` and then change the position type of the original element to `position:absolute` works.

Solution is from rpsep2, but wanted to add this as an answer because I spent so long trying to make this work on Android, and so happy to have a solution. Thanks!